# Unable to access class while method chaining in c++

Tags: c++, scope

I'm working on a library and I'm running into weird issues and I'm not sure what's happening. I broke out the core pieces of the classes I'm writing to replicate the issue.

The gist is that I've got a couple of classes I'm using to manage groupings of indexes for LEDs in a project.

I have a class to keep track of the LED index ranges:

```cpp
class Range
{
public:
  Range () {}
  Range (int start, int end):_start (start), _end (end) {}

private:
  int _start;
  int _end;
};
```

And another class that groups together the Ranges into a Section:

```cpp
class Section
{
public:
  Section () {}

  void addRange(int start, int end)
  {
    addRange(Range (start, end));
  }

  void addRange(Range r)
  {
    if (_rangeCount < TOTAL_RANGES)
      {
        _ranges[_rangeCount] = r;
        _rangeCount++;
      }
  }

  Range getRange(int index)
  {
    return _ranges[index];
  }

  int getRangeCount()
  {
    return _rangeCount;
  }

private:
  int _rangeCount = 0;
  Range _ranges[TOTAL_RANGES];
};
```

These two classes work fine together. I can create a section, add a couple of ranges to it, and then output the total ranges in a section ([you can see a live example here](https://onlinegdb.com/qanMAEY5l)):

```cpp
int main ()
{

  Section s = Section ();
  s.addRange (0, 9);
  s.addRange (10, 19);
  s.addRange (20, 29);

  cout << "range count: " << s.getRangeCount () << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[image: code working]

The snag comes when I try to create a managing class for creating and accessing the sections:

```cpp
class SectionManager {
  public:
    SectionManager(){}
    
    void addSections(int total) {
       for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
           _sections[i] = Section();
       }
       _totalSections += total;
    }
    
    Section getSection(int index){
        return _sections[index];
    }
    
    int getTotalSections(){
        return _totalSections;
    }
  
  private:
    int _totalSections = 0;
    Section _sections[TOTAL_SECTIONS];
  
};
```

When I try to add the SectionManager in, everything compiles fine and seems to work until I go to add ranges:

```cpp
int main ()
{

    SectionManager manager = SectionManager();
    manager.addSections(5);

    cout << "total sections: " << manager.getTotalSections()<< endl;
    
    manager.getSection(0).addRange(0, 9);
    manager.getSection(0).addRange(10, 19);
    manager.getSection(0).addRange(20, 29);
    
    cout << "total ranges: " << manager.getSection(0).getRangeCount() << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

When I do this, the sections get added fine, but when I try to access one of the sections to add a range to it, the range doesn't seem to get added ([the live version of this one can be found here](https://onlinegdb.com/kE4dPLveZ)):

[image: can't seem to add ranges]

I'm not sure what's going wrong. It *feels* like I'm running into some scope issue, but tbh I'm still new enough to cpp that I'm not sure where the snag is coming from (I actually had a hard time figuring out a title for this stackoverflow question b/c I'm not sure how to succinctly describe the issue).

I was thinking "maybe I need to make a pointer in the main function, return the address of the stored section, and then use that to add the range", but then I get an error about trying to take the address of a temporary:

[image: can't handle it with pointers]

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like this may be an easy one for experienced c++ engineers, but I'm new-ish and working/learning in isolation so I'm not seeing what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSection` returns a `Section` by value, so the calling code gets a brand new copy.  You can change your code to return a reference like so:

```
Section& getSection(int index){
    return _sections[index];
}
```

Comment: Same for `Range getRange(int index)`.

Comment: oh, awesome. that makes sense and feels like a bit of a :facepalm:. Thanks for pointing it out. I tried it with the method chaining and it worked!